# Android - PackageManager returns null when using a variable for getLaunchIntentForPackage()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-package-managers, android-appshortcut

Im making a customizable app shortcut(imagebutton) that displays the appicon and launches the app onclick. you can select the app you want to be displayed as shortcut from a popup window in another activity. im achieving this by saving the selected packagename to shared preferences as a string variable and using the getApplicationIcon() and getLaunchIntentForPackage methods in the activity of the shortcut to apply the selected app via packagename.

**My Code**

**ReceiveActivity with the shortcut**

```
public class ReceiveActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton appDisplay;
    private Drawable icon;
    private PackageManager packageManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String packageNameReceive = sharedPreferences.getString("fabKey", "default value");

        try {
            icon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageNameReceive);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        appDisplay = findViewById(R.id.appDisplay);
        appDisplay.setBackground(icon);
        appDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent appLaunch = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageNameReceive);
                startActivity(appLaunch);
            }
        });

    }
```

**MainActivity where the input from popup gets saved**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AppChooserListener  {

    private Button buttonTest;
    private TextView textviewSelected;
    private AppChooserListener activity;
    private Button checkButton;


    private String packageNameSave;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        activity = this;

        buttonTest = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        checkButton = findViewById(R.id.checkButton);

        textviewSelected = findViewById(R.id.textview2);

        buttonTest.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            // The method to display the dialog
            AppChooserDialog.show(v.getContext(), activity);

        });
        checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent checkIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReceiveActivity.class);
                startActivity(checkIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAppChooserSelected(AppItem value) {
        packageNameSave = value.getPackageName();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("fabKey", packageNameSave);
        editor.apply();


    }


}
```

**Logs**

```
    Process: com.example.appchooserold, PID: 25734
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.appchooserold/com.example.appchooserold.ReceiveActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.content.pm.PackageManager.getApplicationIcon(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3677)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3814)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2309)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.content.pm.PackageManager.getApplicationIcon(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.appchooserold.ReceiveActivity.onCreate(ReceiveActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8311)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1385)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3658)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3814) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7944) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
```

I didnt add the dialog because getting the packagename from it was successful.
I discovered after some research that this is related to some changes in higher api levels of android, and i found some solutions like adding queries for VIEW and BROWSABLE in manifest but adding them didnt resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
        appDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                packageManager = getPackageManager();
                Intent appLaunch = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageNameReceive);
                appLaunch.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                appLaunch.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                appLaunch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(appLaunch);
            }
        });
```

I replaced getPackageManager with an Instance of packagemanager via packageManager = getPackageManager() in the onclick method. I dont know how that works tho.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).